# Quick media query glitch

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

Just a quick question from a colleague of mine, I have made his website responsive and at 800px the navigation gets hidden and the mobile menu appears using the standard CSS media query.

Viewing the website on an iPad, it is displaying the mobile menu but my colleague thinks that the iPad should display the website as it is on desktop as it has a screen resolution wider than 800px.

Is this correct and if not, why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An iPad's width in portrait is 768px. Check out [viewport sizes](http://viewportsizes.com). Things get a bit more difficult to understand with higher resolution displays. There's already a question posted about that here at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954953/is-the-ipad-3-device-width-always-768-even-though-the-resolution-width-is-1536-i).

Comment: Adrian, was this helpful?

Comment: Hi Matt, the info was helpful to me but my colleague is still convinced that this is incorrect as a retina iPad would double resolution or something and hence the iPad should show a desktop version of a site as opposed to a mobile site.